Pullbacks in Cat in a 2-dimensional sense
$\newcommand\Fib{\mathrm{Fib}}\newcommand\Cat{\mathrm{Cat}}\newcommand\OpF{\mathrm{OpF}}\DeclareMathOperator\cod{cod}$In proving that a codomain functor from the 2-category $\Fib$ to $\Cat$ is a 2-fibration.
The proof uses the fact that pullbacks in $\Cat$ give 2-cartesian 1-cells. How does this work? And how does one construct a cartesian morphism in $\Fib$?
To prove that the codomain functor from $\OpF$ to $\Cat$ (from the 2-category of opfibrations) is also a 2-fibration,
I have used the definition:
Defn: A 2-functor $P \colon E \to B$ is a 2-fibration if

for any arrow $f\colon I \to PY$ there is a cartesian arrow $g \colon I’ \to Y$;
locally $P$ is an opfibration in that $$P_{X,Y} \colon E(X,Y) \to B(PX,PY)$$ is an opfibration;
the opcartesian 2-cells are closes under horizontal composition.

Then $\cod: \OpF \to \Cat$ is a 2-fibration in the sense of the above definition?

Have you looked at Hermida's paper "Some properties of Fib as a fibred 2-category"?
